# How do I fix the semicolon expected error though semicolons are there?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I created a page that had 4 dynamic nice looking [cards](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/1f995e1d28f068fc0071358967196e66?editors=0010) with data coming from a SharePoint calendar.  Everything was working fine and then all of a sudden it stopped working.  The error points to a line in my getMonth() method which returns the current months name.  The error says **SCRIPT1004: Expected: ';'** In my code all of the semicolons are in place, even though it's not really needed.  I'm using VUE.js.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Below is the code:

```
Vue.component('sp-event-card2', {
      data: function data() {
        return {
          num: 3,
          eventAry: [],
          remainLink: '../Lists/Events/DispForm.aspx?ID=',
          sourceLink: '&source=../Pages/HomePage.aspx'
        };
      },
      created: function created() {
        this.getEvents();
      },
      methods: {
        getEvents: function getEvents() {
          var today = new Date();
        //Want to make sure we show only events that happen today or after
          var endPointUrl = "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Events')/items?$top=3&$orderby=EventDate&$filter=EventDate ge '" + today.toISOString() + "'";
          var that = this;
          axios.get(endPointUrl).then(function (response) {
            that.eventAry = response.data.value;
          });
        },
        stripHtml: function stripHtml(str) {
         // console.log(str);
          var newStr = str.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
          var extractPartialStr = newStr.substring(0, 100);
          return extractPartialStr + "...";
        },
        convertDate: function(dte){
          return moment(dte).format('l');
        },
        getMonth: function(dte){
            let month = 1 + moment(dte, 'YYYY/MM/DD').month();  //<--- Error is here
            let year = moment(dte, 'YYYY/MM/DD').year(); 
            let monthName = moment(month, 'MM').format('MMM');
            return monthName;
        },
        getDayNum: function(dte){
            let day = moment(dte, 'YYYY/MM/DD').date();
            return day;
        }
      },
      template: '\n<div>\n\t<table style="border-style:solid;width:100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">\n<tr>\n     <td id="tdEvent" v-for="event in eventAry" width="31%" height="325px">\n\t{{getMonth(event.EventDate)}}\n{{getDayNum(event.EventDate)}}<hr>\n\t\n\t<a v-bind:href="remainLink + event.Id + sourceLink">{{ event.Title }}</a>\n\t<p>| {{convertDate(event.EventDate)}}</p>\n<p style=font-size:10px;font-weight:bold>{{event.Location}}</p></td>\n</tr>\n</table>\n</div>\n'
    });
```

I think this might be an IE 11 issue.  I just looked at Edge and no error.  Just in IE.  Not sure why

Comment: Can you post the complete error message?

Comment: I know this may not be related to your question but Ive noticed how you define your `data` property and other function properties. You can just define them as follows: `data() { ... }` , `created() { ... }` , `getEvents() { ... }` .

Comment: The complete error message is ```SCRIPT1004: Expected: ';' (42,10)``` @jdaz

Comment: It might be the `let`. Try using `var` instead.